# Why (and how) is Python rounding this math equation?

Tags: python

```
def findDistance():
    first_coord = raw_input("Enter first coordinate set (format x, y): ").split(",")
    second_coord = raw_input("Enter second coordinate set (format x, y): ").split(",")

    x1 = float(first_coord[0])
    x2 = float(second_coord[0])
    y1 = float(first_coord[1])
    y2 = float(first_coord[1])

    print math.sqrt(float(((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1))) + float(((y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1))))
```

Putting in the series (10, 12), (12, 10) gives me 2.0, when the actual distance (rounded somewhat) is `2.82842`. It appears Python is flooring my number. Why and how is this happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Copy&paste error.  The line

```
y2 = float(first_coord[1])
```

should be

```
y2 = float(second_coord[1])
```

Of course the result is also rounded to IEEE double precision, but the reason the result is that far off is the above mistake.

Comment: That was it! Thanks. *facepalm* I was looking for something way less obvious than that.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville:  Always look for the obvious first.  I takes less time.

Comment: Lesson learned, thanks again. Accepting in 5 min.